# CSS/HTML Question: Background on hover and on current page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my page to have a background on my links when I hover over them as well as when the links are the current, active page (kinda like the way dribbble.com does it). I use PHP to check if the current page matches the link to assign an ID, "tab" to my links when they are the current page. Here is my CSS.

```
#tab {
    background: url('../images/underline.gif') no-repeat;
    color: #000;
}
#filter a:hover { url('../images/underline.gif') no-repeat;}
```

The background will show up properly when it is the current page, but will not show up on mouse-over. Any ideas why that would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#tab {
    background: url('../images/underline.gif') no-repeat;
    color: #000;
}
#filter a:hover { 
    background:url('../images/underline.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

Your code is missing the `background:`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
#tab {
background: url('../images/underline.gif') no-repeat;
color: #000;
}
#tab:hover { url('../images/underline.gif') no-repeat;}
```